# How to remote SAS on Unix server from Windows Server (.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sas

I have created a simple asp.net code in VS2010. This code can call a SAS program on unix server through SAS/IOM.  I've published it on local IIS and work good. 
When I published this web applicaton to Windows Server 2012(64bit) IIS and it goes wrong. My local environment is 32 bit.
My error is:

> *[COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {868CEB5F-4D78-43FC-96B4-F5B6C0341151} failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).]*

I tried to do all kind of things. Published web application to x86 and x64 platform. I enabled application pool for 32 bits and not. I tried to compile assemblies for 32 bit and 64 bit, etc.

I have not got base SAS on Windows Server. 
What do I need to install the server to run the program?
Can I install IOM Provider to the server?

Answer (score 1):

On your local server, VS2010 automatically gives permission to the IIS user who's accessing the web application. But here, there might be some authorization issue when You're deploying Your application on Deployment Server with IIS user permission. Please try Setting User Access Rights for the IIS Server accessing Your application directory. This [link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa954062.aspx) might help for setting up user access right. Also see this [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618576/instantiating-a-com-component-fails-with-class-not-registered-when-run-as-adm) for further help.

Comment: Thank you! I try to set permissions to IIS user. But the error is the same.

Comment: I could deploy the application and I see the the web page when I running it from an explorer. But when I try to submit a SAS code, then I get this error. My c# class try to reach sas program on the unix sas server.